# Getting Error Validating SAML message, in ADFS 3.0

Tags: saml, adfs3.0

I am getting an error in single sign on process. I am using sample saml spring extension and integrated it into my existing application with ADFS 3.0, Everything is fine but after successful authentication at adfs side when its redirecting back to my application page its giving an error 'Error validating SAML message' and 'Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation'. Even getting same error when tried using SAML sample application (Not with existing application) with ADFS 3.0, thanks in advance for Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What claims have you configured on the ADFS side to pass back?

Normally you add first name, surname, email.

And a NameID. Usually this is derived from the email or UPN.